# NServiceBus delayed delivery with while loop

Tags: .net, .net-core, nservicebus, servicebus

My scenario is, that when a service order is created the NServiceBus saga should keep on looking for daily pending dues. If dues are available it should sendlocal message to the payment handler. I am continuously using a while loop to check the dues and send a delay message to the payment handler with 20min delay. I am using Azure ServiceBus to send/receive messages.

The problem is the payment handler not receiving the messages. The application is also consuming more memory and the application gets stuck after some time.

Can you suggest an idea to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
while (!Data.IsAllPaymentsDone)
        {
            var paymentRequest = new StartPaymentCommand()
            {
                OrderId = message.OrderId,
                CompanyId = message.CompanyId,
                ItemNumber = message.ItemNumber,
                DueAmount = message.DueAmount
            };

            var options = new SendOptions();
            options.RouteToThisEndpoint();
            options.DelayDeliveryWith(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(TimeInSeconds))); // 20min delay

            await context.Send(paymentOrchestrationRequest, options);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

A saga is a process coordinator. It shouldn't do active work or run continuously, as your `while` loop does. If you need periodic execution of a saga to to occur for a **compensation** action(s), use timeouts.

You'll need to update your design.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will update the saga design.

Comment: Can you provide me an example to use timeouts with 'while' loop or with some time interval?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/timeouts) and  [sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/). There's no loop and shouldn't be in a saga. Refer to the documentation. Saga is a controller, not the executed of the logic.

Comment: I found this scheduling with timers (https://docs.particular.net/samples/scheduling/timer/).

Comment: Scheduling is a different topic. It's good for kicking off reoccurring tasks.